# How to check if a property is $select-ed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am building an OData web API, and I am trying to implement this function to determine whether a given property should be included in a GET response based on the $select value in the query:

```cs
bool IsPropertySelected(ODataQueryOptions options, string propertyName)
```

Browsing docs for `ODataQueryOptions`, there is not an obvious way to do this. I have seen that the library will apply the `$select` clause automatically, but this happens after the response object is generated with all the properties. Some properties are expensive to calculate, so I want to avoid this cost for any properties that are not `$select`-ed.

For example, with an entity schema like:

```cs
class Foo
{
    public string a {get; set;} // From data source A
    public string b {get; set;} // From data source B
    public string c {get; set;} // Aggregated from both data sources
}
```

The controller method would look something like

```cs
public async Task<Foo> GetFoo(string id, ODataQueryOptions options)
{
    var result = new Foo();

    bool needDataFromA = (new List { "a", "c" }).Any(x => IsPropertySelected(options, x));
    bool needDataFromB = (new List { "b", "c" }).Any(x => IsPropertySelected(options, x));

    if (needDataFromA && needDataFromB)
    {
        // get data from A and set result.a
        // get data from B and set result.b
        // set result.c
    }
    else if (needDataFromA)
    {
        // get data from A and set result.a
    }
    else if (needDataFromB)
    {
        // get data from B and set result.b
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'd expect `ODataQueryOptions options` to be `ODataQueryOptions<Foo> options`. Then, you could check selected columns from `options.SelectExpand.RawSelect` or build your logic around `options.SelectExpand.SelectExpandClause.SelectedItems`. Not that `options.SelectExpand` can be null

Comment: @JohnGathogo thanks for the tip. I looked at `SelectedItems` first, but found that there's no accessor for the corresponding property name. That's what prompted me to ask this question, since it made me think there was something fundamentally misguided about this approach. I was hoping not to have to do the string parsing manually, but I guess that will work.